# Atomでファイルを同時に開いた時に、デフォルトで2ウィンドウの横並びになるようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: atom-editor

Atomでファイルを同時に開いた時に、デフォルトで2ウィンドウの横並びになるようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

Comment: 空のウィンドウで開いたときですか？　既にカラムが分割されている状態のときに複数ファイルを開いたらどうなるんでしょうか。それとも常に新しいウィンドウで開くのが良いんでしょうか。

Comment: Atomだけが起動してあって、ファイルを開いていない空の状態で、デスクトップで、２つのファイルを選択して、「開く」にする場合です。これだと2つのタブが重なった状態になるのですが、横に２つ並んだ状態にしたいのです。

Comment: 開いたファイルが3つ以上のときはどうなるのが望ましいのでしょうか。

Comment: 3つ以上の時は特に想定していないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コマンドを自作してみました。Ubuntu 上の Atom 1.16.0 で動作確認しました。

メニューバーの "Edit" → "Init Script" などから `init.coffee` を開いて以下のスクリプトを書きます。

```coffee
_pickFile = () ->
  # https://discuss.atom.io/t/pick-file-like-atom-pickfolder/20815
  remote = require('electron').remote
  remote.dialog.showOpenDialog remote.getCurrentWindow(),
    properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']

atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
  'user:open-two-files': (event) =>
    files = _pickFile()
    if files?.length isnt 2
      atom.notifications.addError "user:open-two-files: Not select two files"
      return
    atom.workspace.open files[0]
    atom.workspace.open files[1],
      split: 'right'
    return
```

`keymap.cson`などにキーコンフィグを書いておけば使えるようになります。

```
'atom-workspace':
  'ctrl-2 ctrl-o': 'user:open-two-files'
```

それなりに限定的なコマンドなので、使いやすいように改造して頂ければと思います（正直ファイルが3つ以上になってくると面倒なので、手でペーンを整理するのが一番速そうだと私は思いますが……）。

- リファレンス

  - [CommandRegistry](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.16.0/CommandRegistry)
  - [Workspace::open](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.16.0/Workspace#instance-open)
  - [dialog.showOpenDialog](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback)

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: @forest もしご自身で改造して満足のいくものができたら、是非自己回答をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私の技術レベルでは、上のようなコマンドを作れるかどうかわかりません。笑　デフォルトの機能では、そういう設定はなさそうですね。